# C# Connect to Mysql db -> cannot connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect from my c# desktop application to my mysql database. But I'm always receiving the following error:

Cannot connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Database class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Infinite_Trainer_v2
{
    class database_connector
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        // Constructor
        public database_connector()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "ip:3306";
            database = "dbName";
            uid = "username";
            password = "password";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        //open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator.");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Select statement
        public bool userCheck(string username, string password)
        {
            string query = "SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";

            bool hasRecords = false;

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        hasRecords = true;
                    }
                }

                dataReader.Close();
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            return hasRecords;
        }
    }
}
```

Database settings:

[Database setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJBHV.png)

Does anyone have a idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: this is the resulting connectionString

SERVER=ip:3306;DATABASE=dbName;UID=username;PASSWORD=password;
are you sure that the syntax is correct? as fas as I know you should write Pwd instead of password and the port is written away from IP

something like Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;

Comment: If you cannot connect I'm sure you get an error message. What is it?